# Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

Tags: swift, swift3

I am attempting to update my app to Swift 3.0 and and have arrived at the error: `Type 'NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element' (aka 'Any') does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`

on line:

```
        self.friends.append(Friend(userName: (detailData as AnyObject).value["userName"] as! String, phoneNumber: detailData.value["phoneNumber"] as! String, status: "Friend", statusSort: 2, name: detailData.value["userName"] as! String, userID: detailData.key))
```

How can I refactor this?

Comment: Code like that is unreadable, undebuggable, and unmanageable. I strongly suggest you split that up into about 6 or so lines so each line is readable and debuggable.

Comment: There is no iterator in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Given your code, I asssume `detailData` is of type `NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element`:

You are casting a `NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element` to `AnyObject`:

```
(detailData as AnyObject)
```

but `NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element`s are structs, so change `AnyObject`to `Any`:

```
(detailData as Any)
```